# Getting Undefined Error when trying to store ajax JSON response into variable

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, json, jqgrid

I am trying to make ajax call and i want to store the `JSON` response into variable.
Because the JSON response, i want to pass it to two `Jqgrids`. One will display half of the response and another will display remaining response. Please help me with some idea to display on `Jqgrids`.

This is how i am trying to store `JSON` response, but i am getting `undefined error` while passing variable to `alert()` function.

```
var form_data;
$(searchBTN).click(function(event))
{
    $.getJSON("search?dealId=" + orderId,
        function(json) {
            form_data = json.CompanyName;
            checkdata();                                        
        });

    function checkData() {
        console.log(form_data);
        alert(form_data);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the value printed by console.log(form_data)?

Comment: You code example as given has a lot of issues and the intent is not clear. I've corrected it a bit as the Click handler was not properly closed. But there is still an ambiguity. Did you intend to include the declaration of checkData() inside the declaration of the anonymous click handler function?

Comment: You need to include more details into your question. Check whether form_data value exists or is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your json data format , means in json array variable keys .I think you accessing wrong variable .Undefined error shows your current key is undefined in json object.For testing use this alert(JSON.parse(json))

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do what I think you intend is as follows:

```
var form_data;
$(searchBTN).click(function(event)) {
    $.getJSON("search?dealId=" + orderId, function(json){
        form_data = json.CompanyName;
        console.log(form_data);
        alert(form_data);               
    });
});
```